# Procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a question. 
I have this oracle code

```
***
create or replace procedure MoveNews(idN in number)
is
v1 number := idN;
begin
  insert into History (IDNEWS, IDSUBNEWS, TITL, TXT, RANKING) 
          (select NEWS.IDNEWS, NEWS.IDSUBT, NEWS.TIT, NEWS.TEXT, NEWS.COUNTT 
           from NEWS 
           where IDNEWS = v1);

  delete from NEWS where IDNEWS = v1;
end;
***
```

but when I run the following happens:

> ORA-04098: trigger 'PROYECTO.HISTORICO_TRG' is invalid and failed re-validation
>   ORA-06512: at "PROYECTO.MOVERNOTICIA", line 5
>   ORA-06512: at line 1
>   04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
>   *Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
>              found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
>              failed for the trigger.
>   *Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
>              disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

I need to enter an ID in the procedure, and copy it data in another table and immediately delete this to the old table.
I appreciate your help

Comment: Looks like there's a failing trigger on the history table, it may not have anything to do with your code being in a procedure as the procedure looks ok.

Comment: There is a `TRIGGER` named `'PROYECTO.HISTORICO_TRG'` in your schema which doesn't compile correctly. Either fix the `TRIGGER` or get rid of it if it isn't required.